# Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected

Tags: scala, apache-toree

The below piece of code does work directly without issues in Spark Shell with Scala 2.11.12, on the Scastie website. But in Jupyter Notebook running Apache Toree, there is a weird error.

```scala
// polymorphic functions

def findFirst[A](as: List[A], p: A => Boolean): Int = {

  val listLength = as.length

  @annotation.tailrec
  def go(n: Int): Int = {

    if (n >= listLength) -1
    else if (p(as(n))) n
    else go(n + 1)

  }

  go(0)

}

def passFun(x: Int): Boolean = x == 2

val l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
// println("The findFirst of function is: ")
println(s"Answer is: ${findFirst(l, passFun)}")
```

There is no error when this code is first executed after a kernel is just started. But immediately when the same cell is executed, the below error is shown:

> The Answer is: 1
> a = 1
> :28: error: missing argument list for method findFirst
> Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
> You can make this conversion explicit by writing `findFirst _` or `findFirst(_,_)` instead of `findFirst`.
> findFirst
> ^
> lastException: Throwable = null
> findFirst: [A](as: List[A], p: A => Boolean)Int
> 1

The error is gone when the kernels are restarted. Can someone please let me know if they know the solution or the cause of this issue?

Comment: Be aware that your recursive method is incredibly inefficient and will slow to a crawl on a long list. The `length` operation reads the whole list each time, and the `as(n)` operation reads the list up to element `n`

Comment: I don't know Toree, but your error is a compilation-time error, not a run-time error. I don't see how "restarting a kernel" could affect that.

Comment: @Tim - Thanks for the pointer. Valid input. I shall change the code.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul - I am not sure I understand your comment. As stated in the question, the code compiles well with Scastie and scala shell on laptop. If there is indeed an issue with the code, then it shouldnt compile on Scastie and Scala shell right?

Comment: Correct. But it's still a compilation time error. So happening when code is compiled,not when it is executed. I was pointing that out in the hope it will help you narrow down the issue